# PHP script can not write to file with email piping

Tags: php, email, permissions, piping

I have a simple script written to process received email.  Here are the tested scenarios:

A. Script function is to send an email indicating an email was received at piped address.

-tested by browser - Success

-tested by CLI - Success

-tested by piping - Success

B. Script function is to parse and write files to folder, AND send email indicating email was received at piped address

-tested by browser - Files written and email sent.

-tested by CLI - Files written and email sent.

-tested by piping - Files NOT written, BUT email is sent.

I have simplified the script to the basic function of reading and writing the piped message.  I suspect the issue is a permission problem, but I can not find any supporting evidence.

I am not fluent in CLI, but can perform some task. I am not sure where to look for log files for the piped scenario.

Piping works just fine in all tested scenarios.  Here is the simplified code that fails when invoked by piping:

```
#!/usr/bin/php -q
<?php
/* Read the message from STDIN */
$fd = fopen("php://stdin", "r"); 
$email = ""; // This will be the variable holding the data.
while (!feof($fd)) {
$email .= fread($fd, 1024);
}
fclose($fd);
/* Saves the data into a file */
$fdw = fopen("/my/folder/mail.txt", "w");
fwrite($fdw, $email);
fclose($fdw);
/* Script End */
```

Thanks for any help.

Modified code to:

```
#!/usr/bin/php -q
<?php
/* Read the message from STDIN */
$email = file_get_contents('php://stdin');

/* Saves the data into a file */
$fdw = fopen("/Volumes/Cobra/Sites/email/mail.txt", "w+");
if (! $fdw) {
    error_log("Unable to open mail.txt for output.", 1, "myemail@mydomain.com", "From: admin@mydomain.com");
} else {
    fwrite($fdw, $email);
}

fclose($fdw);

/* Script End */
```

Error message was emailed.  Now what? What user does the pipe-invoked script run as?

Comment: Enable error logging and log all errors including warnings and notices. Then check the error log after you've invoked the pipe. It shows you the error(s) you have. If you don't understand the error messages, add them to your question and ask what you don't understand. http://php.net/error-reporting

Comment: Please forgive my ignorance... I have error reporting on, but my error does not happen when I test this through a browser.  I have an Xserve running Snow Leopard Server.  The only log files I see are for web sites.  Is there a php log somewhere that I can view?

Comment: Yes PHP has it's own logging - if you configure PHP error logging (see the link in my prev comment, scroll a bit, all php ini settings related to error handling incl. logging are on that page). Configure it, then you can check that error log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's a permissions problem, then either fopen will return FALSE on failure. You're not checking for that case, and assumes everything worked. Try

```
$fd = fopen('php://stdin', 'r');
if (!$fd) {
   die("Unable to open stdin for input");
}

$fdw = fopen(...);
if (!$fdw) {
   die("Unable to open mail.txt for output");
}
```

If neither die() triggers, then it's not a permissions issue.

As one stylistic thing, unless your real code is much more complicated and does want to process stdin in chunks, you could just do:

```
$email = file_get_contents('php://stdin');
```

Comment: I added the die() condition. This is where I am lost... where do I look for the message "Unable to open mail.txt for output."?

Comment: cron jobs email their output to the account that they ran under. You could use something like `error_log('...')` to have PHP write out the message as well, but then you're in the same boat - if the error log file can't be written to, you won't get any messages.

Comment: If the error log can't be written, configure it to syslog (temporarily). http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php - see destination parameter.

Comment: getmyuid() returned the my user name (owner of the script).  posix_getuid() returned the system user account for web services when tested through a browser; and returned a 10 digit unrecognized number when tested via pipe.  I checked user tables including system users, no such number exist.

Comment: I (temporarily) changed permissions on the destination folder to everyone:read/write.  Pipe script worked.  Is there a way to designate (in the php code) the user a script runs as?

Comment: not really. you can't switch to another uid unless you start out as root to begin with. otherwise it'd be easy to go "switch to seekrit_account uid and let me read their files".

Comment: That makes sense.  This has been most helpful. Thank you both.